# Easily import a MySQL --tab dump

Tags: mysql, mysqlimport

I have dumped a MySQL database with the `--tab` option, which creates 2 files per table (a SQL file with the `create table` and a tab-separated-values file with the data).

Is there an easy way to import this directory of files back into a MySQL server? I can't find the option in `mysqlimport`.

Answer (score 4):

```
for i in `ls *.sql`; do 
  sql_file=$i; 
  table_name=`echo $sql_file | sed "s/.sql$//"`
  mysql -u root database_name < $sql_file
  echo "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$table_name.txt' INTO TABLE $table_name" | mysql -u root database_name
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this several ways - the most direct would be

```
mysql db < sql_structure_file
```

This creates the tables. Then do (from mysql client)

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE tab_delimited_file INTO TABLE
```

(with appropriate names, delimiters, etc )

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this bash script which first imports all the sql files to build the tables, then the txt files. The data is loaded using background processes in parallel — basically emulating the multi-thread option in `mysqlimport`.  Usage is like this:

```
./import_table.sh database_name /path/to/dump/files
```

**SCRIPT:**

```bash
#!/bin/bash

DIR=$(echo $2 | sed 's/\/$//')

function import_sql() {
    mysql $1 < $2;
    echo "mysql $1 < '$2'";
}

function import_txt() {
    mysqlimport --silent $1 $2;
    echo "mysqlimport --silent $1 '$2'";
}

for filename in $DIR/*.sql; do
    [ -e "$filename" ] || continue
    import_sql $1 $filename &
done
wait
echo 'ALL SQL IMPORTED';

for filename in $DIR/*.txt; do
   [ -e "$filename" ] || continue
   import_txt $1 $filename &
done
wait
echo 'ALL TXT IMPORTED';
```